# vnstat breaks after 200TBs of transfer

Tags: permissions, vnstat

I have a high bandwidth server that uses ~3000GBs per day. I use vnstat to track this. Almost two weeks ago, it stopped working. I updated permissions and gave all privileges to the "vnstat" user:

```
# ls -las
total 128
  4 drwxr-xr-x  2 vnstat vnstat   4096 Dec 11 16:10 .
  4 drwxr-xr-x 59 root   root     4096 Dec 18 00:05 ..
120 -rw-r--r--  1 vnstat vnstat 122880 Dec 11 16:05 vnstat.db
```

This is what vnstat looks write now (I'm writing this on 12/22):

```
Database updated: 2021-12-11 16:05:00

   ens3 since 2021-09-08

          rx:  112.88 TiB      tx:  87.08 TiB      total:  199.97 TiB

   monthly
                     rx      |     tx      |    total    |   avg. rate
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
       2021-11     52.63 TiB |   40.63 TiB |   93.27 TiB |  316.51 Mbit/s
       2021-12     20.51 TiB |   14.90 TiB |   35.41 TiB |  337.84 Mbit/s
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
     estimated     59.59 TiB |   43.28 TiB |  102.87 TiB |

   daily
                     rx      |     tx      |    total    |   avg. rate
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
     2021-12-10     1.83 TiB |    1.38 TiB |    3.21 TiB |  326.93 Mbit/s
     2021-12-11     1.53 TiB |    1.14 TiB |    2.67 TiB |  406.13 Mbit/s
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
     estimated      2.29 TiB |    1.70 TiB |    3.99 TiB |
```

How can I fix this? Can I force the program to update? I've tried the u flag but it seems to be disabled in the version I'm on. My Ubuntu version is 21.04.

Comment: Silly question, but have you confirmed that vnstat is running? `ps aux | grep vnstatd` should answer this question ...

Comment: AHHHH why did I forget to do that??? I'm running it with systemctl now, I'll let you know if the db updates

Comment: Do `sudo lshw -C network` and confirm that `ens3` is still the correct interface.